# Asterisk, make a call from command line

Tags: centos, asterisk, voip

I'm trying to make a call from command line, I have everything working, but I need to make a script that makes a call when I execute it. I tried doing it in Asterisk's command line, using dial, and after my number extension, but it isn't working.

Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks, regards!

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far

Comment: Finally I could doing this simple script, sorry but I'm a begginer with asterisk, and I have to practice more.

Channel: SIP/Username
Application: Playback
Data: Probando

Answer (score 1):

```
asterisk -rx "channel originate SIP/yourprovider_name/123456789 application playback i_am_beginner"
```

However it is REALY REALY bad idea due to security and perfomance issues.

Use call files or AMI action Originate